# SQL NOT LIKE with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-like

I'm using MYSQL and can't get a NOT LIKE working with multiple JOINS.
I have 3 tables which look like this:

Parents (Table1):

```
+------------+-------+-----+
|  ParentID  | Name  | AGE |
+------------+-------+-----+
| 1          | Peter | 26  |
| 2          | Karl  | 33  |
| 3          | Tessa | 43  |
+------------+-------+-----+
```

Kids (Table2):

```
    +------------+-------+-----+
    |  KidID     | Name  | AGE |
    +------------+-------+-----+
    | 1          | Mike  | 3   |
    | 2          | Mike  | 13  |
    | 3          | Jenna | 4   |
    | 4          | Jessi | 14  |
    +------------+-------+-----+
```

Parents_Kids (Table3):

```
    +-----------+-------+
    | ParentID  | KidID |
    +-----------+-------+
    | 1         | 2     |
    | 1         | 4     |
    | 2         | 1     |
    | 3         | 3     |
    +-----------+-------+
```

Now i want to get all parent names who don't have a kid named Mike or any form of Mike in there name.

I tried this:

```
SELECT p.name
FROM PARENTS p JOIN
     Parents_Kids pk
     ON pk.ParentID = p.ParentID JOIN
     Kids k
     ON k.KidID = pk.KidID
WHERE k.Name NOT LIKE '%mike%';
```

But the result is wrong with this query.
If i try this query with LIKE it works correctly but not with NOT LIKE.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that are returned.

Comment: Make sure you're also careful with capitalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't want to select the parent if atleast one of his/her kids have a name like mike. You can use `having` to filter such cases.

```
SELECT p.name 
FROM PARENTS p 
JOIN Parents_Kids pk ON pk.ParentID=p.ParentID 
JOIN Kids k ON k.KidID=pk.KidID 
group by p.name
having count(case when k.name like '%mike%' then 1 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You say your query works correctly with `LIKE`, so a way to get the other parent names is this:

```
SELECT name
FROM parents
WHERE name not in (SELECT p.name
                   FROM PARENTS p JOIN
                        Parents_Kids pk
                        ON pk.ParentID = p.ParentID JOIN
                        Kids k
                        ON k.KidID = pk.KidID
                   WHERE k.Name LIKE '%mike%')
```